# Implicit data members for @synthesize - good practice or bad habit?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Today, I got a link to [a long list of coding guidelines](http://ironwolf.dangerousgames.com/blog/archives/913), proclaiming to be "code commandments". A good read, and full of new insights to me. Among the list, somewhere along 25% of the scrollbar, I come across something new to me: Implicit data member creation.

Although every tutorial, book and video I've read or watched about Objective-C always performs the triad of `NSNumber *number | @property NSNumber *number | @synthesize number`, these commandments now tell me I can simply *omit the first step* (data member declaration in the interface) because @synthesize will create one on the fly. Say what!?

With a little disbelief I deleted several of my data member declarations, and indeed, my app still works like a charm. Less typing, less reading, less chance for typos.

Sounds to me like a win-win-win, but is it really good practice?

I'm asking this question out of pure disbelief that all the tutorials, books and videos are teaching the wrong lesson, at least too much of it, or that I've been not paying attention in class...

Cheers,
EP.

*Edit: Although I copied the expression "data member" from the linked post, it is more commonly described with the word "ivar", just a good one to have in here for search friendliness. This also takes care of my former confusion over property/ivar/member naming :).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synthesized instance variables are a feature of the modern Objective-C 2.0 runtime. This means they're available on x86_64, on ARM, and as of Xcode 3.2, on the iPhone Simulator. It means exactly what you suggested - you can omit the ivar declaration, and the @synthesize line will generate the ivar for you. The performance of this is exactly the same as declaring the ivar explicitly, but it has the very important benefit of not polluting your header file with private implementation details.

Comment: Nice, sounds like a "yes, good practice!", or is there a nuance?

Comment: Yes, good practice! Only nuance is you cannot reference the ivar explicitly before the @synthesize line., but in general that comes first anyway.

Comment: One other nuance: It's not a good practice if you want to support Macs with Core Duos. Otherwise it's awesome.

Comment: Great insight chuck! With the ARM processor though, I should be set on any iOS device that runs 4.0 or later, right?

Comment: Any iOS device, period. They're all ARM.

Comment: It is not available on 32 bit intel, no matter how new the computer is. 64 bit is not always beneficial, and increases memory usage. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score -3):

I have begun the practice of removing synthesized properties from the Objective-C classes I create. The primary reason for this is because there is a distinct difference between:

```
self.myNSObject = [NSObject new];
```

and

```
myNSObject = [NSObject new];
```

Specifically, if `myNSObject` is declared as a @property(retain, ...) the former line will result in a retainCount of 2 while the latter will result in a retainCount of 1. This means that unless you are *extremely careful* about *every* assignment to `myNSObject` you run the risk of getting your retain/release balancing wrong.

The other reasons you specify are also very valid. There is a lot going on in the synthesized routines that my brain doesn't account for when I'm reading the code I've written, so a lot is taking place behind the scenes that I'm not thinking of yet am accountable for. It's for very a similar reason I've abandoned Apple's Interface Builder.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn the memory management fundamentals. Espousing the removal of properties merely because you do not understand memory management semantics is terrible advice.

Comment: I understand memory management. What I disapprove of is Objective-C having widely varying postconditions on statements whose syntaxes are only slightly different.

Comment: The rules pretty much are new/create/alloc should be paired with a (auto)release, so if you 'd pair your self.myNSObject = [[NSObject new] autorelease], you'd be set. But regardless, it is not an answer to the question. When already using @property, is it good or bad practice to omit the data member declaration?

Comment: I see; I misread your original question. All the same you could just as easily write `myNSObject = [NSObject new]`, have less code to maintain, it's easier to read, and you'd be just as set.

Comment: Note that dot syntax and `@property` are entirely orthogonal. Note also that *not* using @property and @synthesize means you are losing correctness and efficiency.   There is fragility as you describe, but it is easily resolved by explicitly naming your instance variables and using something like `@synthesize foo = _foo;`.  -1 for mentioning `retainCount` as an absolute value;  the value is coincidental to the internal implementation of the class.

Comment: @bbum: You make a good point about the explicitly (re)naming the variables to which the synthesizing should refer to. I wasn't mentioning the retainCount as much for its absolute value, because you're right. Rather I mentioned it to highlight the postcondition fragility.

Comment: @fbrereto Your post seems to be suggesting that having memory management semantics built into properties causes errors due to over-retaining. It is in fact the opposite that is true. With ivars you have to always know the correct semantics for use, and always remember to release the old value when appropriate. With properties, you assign a non-owned reference and trust the property to do what is needed to store the value. As an analogy, you would never say `[self setMyNSObject:[NSObject new]]`.

Comment: @Kevin: As far as I know `self.myNSObject = [NSObject new]` is syntactic sugar for `[self setMyNSObject:[NSObject new]]`, hence the need to wrap the call in an 'autorelease'. All in all it's the compiler not catching the difference in postcondition state between the ivar and property-based calls that leaves me the most irked. bbum's recommendation of renaming the ivar and assigning it on synthesis is the gem of this entire thread.

Comment: @Kevin: +1 for bringing up `[self setMyNSObject:[NSObject new]]`, but I want to mention that it's not just an analogy; it's exactly identical! :)